# Downloading the binary code from an AT89S52 chip

Tags: download, atmel

I have an AT89S52, and I want to read the program burned on it.
Is there a way to do it with the programming interface?
(I am well aware it will be assembly code, but I think I can handle it, since I'm looking for a specific string in that code)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be able to (at all easily anyway) -- that chip has three protection bits that are intended to prevent you from doing so. If you're dealing with some sort of commercial product, chances are pretty good that those bits will be set.

Reference: [Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/dyn/resources/prod_documents/doc1919.pdf), page 20, section 17.